Drop event on div is Inconsistent in chrome
My drop events fires on Firefox every time but it is inconsistent in Chrome, where it works inconsistently. What should I do to make it consistent?
I tried setting the child pointer-events to none but that did not fix the issue.
<div class="project-show" :class="{ 'dragging': is_dragging }" @dragover.prevent.stop="is_dragging=true" @dragleave="is_dragging=false" @drop.prevent.stop="uploadAssets">
  ...some other components
</div>

.dragging {
  &>* {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}

